# Rootless Docker - how do I access a Docker volume from the host?

Tags: docker

I've created a container and used the volume switch to share a directory between the host and my container, e.g. `-v /home/docker/mydirectory:/etc/myapp/directory` I can see the directory as root or a sudo user, but my docker daemon is running under the docker user (no sudo privileges) for security reasons, however, that user has no rights to the files in that directory on the host. The owner of the directory is a number (165605):

```
drwx------ 19 165605 docker mydirectory
```

As you can see, only the 165605 "user" has access by default.

How do I assign or ensure the docker user has access when creating the container?

---

I’m having another go at re-wording this after some research.
Basically, the way I understand it, one of the purposes of volumes (apart from persisting data after the container is destroyed) is to be able to access (and back up or modify) container data from the host OS.
Now when running the container as a non-sudo user (no root mode), I can create the volume, inspect and access it using the same user that I configured Docker under (user name=docker, group=docker), but when I deploy a container and use the -v option to connect my volume to an existing directory in my container, I have no access to the data in the volume. Rights for the volume directory (created under /home/docker/.local/share/docker/volumes) are as follows:

```
drwx-----x 3 docker docker 4096 Oct 14 10:33 test
```

…but to the files within my test volume:

```
drwx------ 19 165605 165605 4096 Oct 14 11:50 _data
```

My docker user has no access at that point, only ‘`165605`’.
I can ssh in as a sudo user and access the contents fine. How do I enable access to my docker user to the test volume from the host OS when using no-root mode?

Comment: Your policies are inconsistent. Your mydirectory also has "docker" group, yet you grant zero permission to the docker group. Try chmod'ing permissions to allow docker group to access?

Comment: The subdirectory exists in the /home/docker directory and was created by user docker of group docker before the docker run command (both group and user had full access).  After docker run is what you see.  Docker user and group no longer have rights to the directory.  This was the result of the docker run execution.  Is the only way to resolve it really to manually assign the docker group access again using a sudo account?  Is there another way to use the volumes switch for different results?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure for your set-up. I don't have a _user_ docker, only a group. I run docker as a regular user, and share any given volume as needed. But I don't have the security needs that you do. Is the code in the container setting the permission on the shared volume from its side?

Comment: I'm using the PostGIS container, it seems to be normal behavior for some reason. If I create a new volume, I have access to the volume, the minute I populate that volume using docker run -v, I can't see the data within it from my host shell (using the same account the docker daemon is run under).  I can only see it with root even though it exists within the docker user's home directory.

Comment: I don't have a /home/docker directory -- all shared volumes are in my regular user directory -- maybe there's some quirk associated with having a docker user per se, and a shared volume in that formal user home? Perhaps test the same set up for whether it's the PostGIS container specifically -- share a volume to this container in your home directory, as well as sharing this /home/docker/.../test to a different container than PostGIS.

Comment: I also wonder whether we're looking at the right thing ... is this /home/docker/.local/share .../test directory the thing that you're sharing under the `docker run -v` command line option? As in `docker run -v /home/docker/.local/.../test:<containerroot>/<path>`? Or is that the directory that you found that docker appears to create for its container usage? Try for sure to share a different, regular directory in the running user's /home/user/... space?

Comment: No, I'm specifying the host directory and container directory.  What I have since found is if I share a directory that does not exist yet in the container, it gets created and I have full access to the existing host directory (and any files I put in there).  If I specify a directory that exists in the container, it seems the rights are changed on the host directory and files that are copied from the container to the host... and I don't have access.  So rule of thumb is you only have local access from the host if you're adding a directory and files to the container.